# keras's binary_crossentropy loss function range

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

When I use keras's `binary_crossentropy` as the [loss function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3270) (that calls [tensorflow's sigmoid_cross_entropy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/600caf99897e82cd0db8665acca5e7630ec1a292/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L107), it seems to produce loss values only between `[0, 1]`. However, the equation itself

```
# The logistic loss formula from above is
#   x - x * z + log(1 + exp(-x))
# For x < 0, a more numerically stable formula is
#   -x * z + log(1 + exp(x))
# Note that these two expressions can be combined into the following:
#   max(x, 0) - x * z + log(1 + exp(-abs(x)))
# To allow computing gradients at zero, we define custom versions of max and
# abs functions.
zeros = array_ops.zeros_like(logits, dtype=logits.dtype)
cond = (logits >= zeros)
relu_logits = array_ops.where(cond, logits, zeros)
neg_abs_logits = array_ops.where(cond, -logits, logits)
return math_ops.add(
    relu_logits - logits * labels,
    math_ops.log1p(math_ops.exp(neg_abs_logits)), name=name)
```

implies that the range is from `[0, infinity)`. So is Tensorflow doing some sort of clipping that I'm not catching? Moreover, since it's doing `math_ops.add()` I'd assume it'd be for sure greater than 1. Am I right to assume that loss range can definitely exceed 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cross entropy function is indeed not bounded upwards. However it will only take on large values if the predictions are very wrong. Let's first look at the behavior of a randomly initialized network.

With random weights, the many units/layers will usually compound to result in the network outputing approximately uniform predictions. That is, in a classification problem with `n` classes you will get probabilities of around `1/n` for each class (0.5 in the two-class case). In this case, the cross entropy will be around the entropy of an n-class uniform distribution, which is `log(n)`, *under certain assumptions* (see below).

This can be seen as follows: The cross entropy for a single data point is `-sum(p(k)*log(q(k)))` where `p` are the true probabilities (labels), `q` are the predictions, `k` are the different classes and the sum is over the classes. Now, with hard labels (i.e. one-hot encoded) only a single `p(k)` is 1, all others are 0. Thus, the term reduces to `-log(q(k))` where `k` is now the correct class. If with a randomly initialized network `q(k) ~ 1/n`, we get `-log(1/n) = log(n)`.

We can also go of the definition of the cross entropy which is generally `entropy(p) + kullback-leibler divergence(p,q)`. If `p` and `q` are the same distributions (e.g. `p` is uniform when we have the same number of examples for each class, and `q` is around uniform for random networks) then the KL divergence becomes 0 and we are left with `entropy(p)`.

Now, since the training objective is usually to *reduce* cross entropy, we can think of `log(n)` as a kind of worst-case value. If it ever gets higher, there is probably something wrong with your model. Since it looks like you only have two classes (0 and 1), `log(2) < 1` and so your cross entropy will generally be quite small.

Comment: Can you please expand on this statement "In this case, the cross-entropy will be around the entropy of an n-class uniform distribution which is `log(n)`" I think that's key to this answer and it would be helpful to have more back information on this.

Comment: I added some explanations, hope that helps.